# Deno Watcher | Uncaught AddrInUse: Only one usage of each socket address

Tags: javascript, typescript, deno

When I use Deno watcher after save file and Restarting deno watcher

make this problem and show in Terminal:

```
Watcher File change detected! Restarting!
    error: Uncaught AddrInUse: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (os error 10048)
Watcher Process finished. Restarting on file change...
```

and after save app.ts again show this lines in Terminal:

```
Watcher File change detected! Restarting!
error: Uncaught AddrInUse: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (os error 10048)
    core.runMicrotasks();
         ^
    at Object.runMicrotasks (deno:core/01_core.js:377:30)
    at processTicksAndRejections (https://deno.land/std@0.164.0/node/_next_tick.ts:62:10)
Watcher Process finished. Restarting on file change...
```

My app.ts:

```
import express, { Express, Request, Response } from "npm:express@4.18";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'npm:uuid@9.0.0';
const app: Express = express();

app.use("/", (_req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send(`uuid: ${uuidv4()}.`);
})

app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log("App Running: http://localhost:8000");
});
```

Used command:
`deno run --allow-all --watch app.ts`

Deno version:

```
deno 1.28.0 (release, x86_64-pc-windows-msvc) | v8 10.9.194.1 | typescript 4.8.3
```

Os: Windows 11

Comment: Looks like it might be a bug in deno. If you want you can create an issue in their github repository: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues

Comment: Tested locally and reproduced the bug, not sure if the same behavior is observed with native deno http server instead of express

Comment: I went ahead and made and issue: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/16699

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Deno (see https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/16699#issuecomment-1322854380) and it was patched in Deno v1.28.2.